# Combining React-Native for Android with existing android codebase?

Tags: android, mobile, react-native

I have a huge android codebase for an app : It's basically a SDK where all the business logic is implemented. 
I have a basic native UI. I want a way to quickly iterate on the UI : that's why I thought about React-Native for Android.

Do you think the interop will be easy or is it difficult to integrate it with an existing codebase ? anybody has had an experience with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way react-native UI can interact your SDK code is if  you expose your SDK's API by building a NativeModule (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content). Building NativeModules can be from anything very simple to large depending on your SDK.